# node_type page not accessable for admin

Tags: nodes

I am using Drupal 6. I am unable to access node type edit pages. because it redirects it to site data management page. i searched on google but not find any reason. can any one suggest what is the reason.

Comment: It might just be a permission issue. You can try visiting `yoursite/node/%nid/edit` to check if it is accessible. Just replace `%nid` with the node id of any page of the site.

Comment: i am talking about node type, not about nid. whole site is working perfect except this page. and there is no any redirect define. so how it redirect? it is question

Comment: i want to enable image module for node item, but i can not access node type page.

Comment: the problem is some where in database. i tested it but what problem can be i don't knew.